# По поводу куба, который должен разворачивать сторону

Tags: jquery

Почему код не выполняется по очереди? Делает одновременно. Как его можно заставить выполнять сначала разворот, потом уже увеличение высоты и ширины контейнера `.cube`, и потом уже увеличение высоты и ширины у самой стороны `#side2` (к примеру). Свойство `delay` не работает, не знаю почему, может не туда ставлю. Подскажите пожалуйста если можете.

JS:

```
$(".link2").on("click", function() {
  $('.cube').css("transform", "rotate3d(0,1,0,270deg)");
  $('.main-cube').css("top", "10%");
  $(".cube").addClass("active-cube");
  $('#side2').delay(2500)
             .animate({ width: "90vw" }, 1000 )
             .animate({ height: "90vh" }, 1000 );
});
```

CSS:

```
.active-cube {
  width: 90vw;
  height: 45vh;
}
```

Comment: Я не вижу анимационного изменения размеров `.cube`

Comment: анимация там не нужна. С помощью addclass просто расширяется контейнер, в котором уже дается место для анимационного расширения #side2

Answer (score 0):

`delay` работает, ваша ошибка не воспроизводится:

```js
$(".link2").on("click", function() {
  $('.container').css("transform", "rotate3d(0,1,0,270deg)");
  $(".container").addClass("active-cube");
  $('#side2').delay(2500)
             .animate({ width: "90vw" }, 1000 )
             .animate({ height: "90vh" }, 1000 );
});
```

```css
BODY {
  perspective: 500px;
  perspective-origin: center -5em;
  }
.side,
.container {
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  }

.container {
  margin: 5em auto 0;
  border: 2px dotted white;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform ease 1s;
  }
  .container:before,
  .container:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 10em;
    height: 10em;
    border: 2px dotted white;
    }
    .container:before {
      transform: rotateX(90deg);  
      }
    .container:after {
      transform: rotatey(90deg);  
      }

.side {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  border: 2px solid white;
  opacity: .7;
  }

.back {
  transform: translateZ(-5em);
  background: orange;
  }
.left {
  transform: translateX(-5em) rotateY(90deg);
  background: lightgreen;
  }
.right {
  transform: translateX(5em) rotateY(90deg);
  background: yellowgreen;
  }
.top {
  transform: translateY(-5em) rotateX(90deg);
  background: skyblue;
  }
.bottom {
  transform: translateY(5em) rotateX(90deg);
  background: steelblue;
  }
.front {
  transform: translateZ(5em);
  background: gold;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="link2">link 2</a>
 
 <div class="container">
    <div class="back side"></div>
    <div class="left side"></div>
    <div id="side2" class="right side"></div>
    <div class="top side"></div>
    <div class="bottom side"></div>
    <div class="front side"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Откуда вы все эти стили взяли?

Comment: Интересный у вас подход с контейнером. У меня три уровня у вас два, возможно в этом моя проблема. То есть у меня сразу идет main-cube контейнер для куба, потом .cube это уже непосредственно сам куб(pos relation) и side1 side2 и так далее(pos absolute) это сами стороны.  Ида, вопрос а куда исчезает активная сторона. Я в codepen делал ваш вариант и при повороте активная сторона увеличивается и улетает в непонятные дали:)